# Restrict Video File to download

Tags: asp.net, video-streaming, hosting

I am trying to build a spiritual website for one company and they are planning to `embed` some videos in their website.

And they are requesting me to make their `videos` private as they don't want the users to download them as they are collecting some amount for the classes and they would like to give  those videos at a particular time on the website for the registered users.

If we go for live streaming it's costing much so we are planning to host it on the same website and remove them after a period of time.

So I would like to know what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What about combination of PayPal Subscriptions and Forms Authentication?

Comment: some say that it's not reliable and how to do with forms authentication:)

Comment: It's pretty reliable. All you have to do is find a way to display video per user (SubscriberID). Seems like a basic exercise in DB design ;-) Forms authentication to get them into the Web display page then retrieve video based on their status.

Comment: Oh! Ok..I got it.I'll try and let you know. Thnks for the new turn.

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Comment: Yes I have tried it and worked well for the authentiation part but restrition for download I'm trying to use flash video so that the users unable to download it from here  http://www.aspnet-video.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a combination of PayPal Subscriptions and Forms Authentication. Use the PayPal IPN to get the users status (if they're paid up or not) and associate this with the transaction ID and user ID.

They will only get access to the video class page if they are authenticated. At that point, you can retrieve their subscription status from the DB and grant them access if they are paid up. If not, provide a friendly message and link to PayPal.

[ASP.NET PayPal Subscriptions IPN](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/07/10/ASPNET-PayPal-Subscriptions-IPN.aspx) [caveat: own blog]

[How to set up a Paypal Subscription](http://youtu.be/JFADJVtXfTc)

You may have to use profiles to store extra information per user. If this is the case and you are using ASP.NET WAP (2.0+), then use the following info to set that up:

[ASP.NET Profiles in Web Application Projects](http://leedumond.com/blog/asp-net-profiles-in-web-application-projects/)

Answer (score 1):

Serving videos in a website can be done using either streaming or progressive download. The latter is technically similar to any other download, i.e. if users find the video's URL, they can download it.

You can write client-side code for hashing a one-time token to try and obfuscate the URL of the video file, but essentially committed users can hack their way into the download URL.

Your other option is to use DRM, which will allow you to restrict playing the file even if downloaded. But that might actually cost you more than streaming. (It will also provide better protection of your video, as streamed videos can also be saved on users' computers if they know how to).